# This is a program to recursively calculate the reverse of a string but it's not printing anything

Tags: c++

What I have done is created a global array to store the reversed string.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char arr[10];
int c = 1;

string Reverser(string z)
{
    arr[c] = z[(z.size() - c)];

    c++;

    if (c == (z.size() + 1))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {

        Reverser(z);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    string z;
    cin >> z;
    string Reverser(z);

    for (int i = 1; i <= z.size(); i++)
    {

        cout << arr[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to dry run it but I can't really find any error.

Comment: `return` type `string` and `return 0;` will crash. It tries to create a `string` from what is at address `0`, which does not work.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `string Reverser(z);`?

Comment: `Reverser` is supposed to return the reversed string, not store it in a global variable. `string Reverser(z);` declares a local variable called "Reverser", which is a copy of `z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `std::stringstream` and pass it by reference in your recursive function. Also, you can pass the string by reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void reverse(const std::string& a, std::stringstream& ss, unsigned int pos)
{
    ss << a[pos];
    if (pos == 0) return;
    
    reverse(a, ss, pos - 1);
}

void reverse(const std::string& a, std::stringstream& ss)
{
    reverse(a, ss, a.length() - 1);
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string input = "Hello";
    reverse(input, ss);
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```